# Python google search and get immediate answer

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to make a voice assistant with python. I need to know how to find the immediate answer to a question that comes up in bold when you look it up on google. For instance [http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what+is+the+capital+of+ethiopia](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what%20is%20the%20capital%20of%20ethiopia) is Addis Ababa. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how to immediately get redirected to the "I'm feeling lucky", then append this to the query string: `btnI=1`. Or, as a complete URL based on your example:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what+is+the+capital+of+ethiopia&btnI=1

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful.